# How do you auto-type the contents of the clipboard from the host into a guest Virtual Box instance?

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard

In the case where clipboard sharing is not possible, because there is just a console and no GUI.

Comment: Which operating system is the host?

Comment: soz, I'm interested in Linux/Ubuntu. But, I think it is ok to keep the question operating system nonspecific.

Answer (score 9):

Can do that with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) on a **windows host**.

I wrote this script which sends the contents of the clipboard once you press `Win`+`v`.

Save it as `sendClipboard.ahk`:

```
; win + v
#v::
  SendRaw %clipboard%
```

if you've installed AutoHotKey, you can execute it by double-clicking the file. a "H" icon will appear in the system tray notification area.

Now you will be able to use `Win`+`v` to send the clipboard contents as text to the active window.

**NOTE**: don't forget to press your HOST key, usually the right `Ctrl`, in order to return the focus to your host os, before using `Win`+`v`.

**WARNING** The script is basic and does **not** try to protect you from inserting eg. a big image data from the clipboard as text... so it requires you to understand and know what you are doing to make use of it.

Comment: If you use AutoHotKey 2.0, use the following syntax for the script: `#v::SendText A_Clipboard`

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot install Guest additions to share the clipboard, you need to create a script on the host OS that stores the clipboard text in a file in a shared folder. On the guest OS you need to create a script that reads any new file in the shared folder and types the content of the textfile.

---

**old, false answer** (may still be useful to others)

In order to enable sharing the clipboard between your guest OS and your host OS, you have to install Guest additions ([How do I enable the shared clipboard in VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/42134/virtualbox-shared-clipboard)).

Then you need to run a script on your guest OS that listens for clipboard changes. If you use Windows, you can accomplish something like that using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm#OnClipboardChange). The script will type the content of the clipboard as text when the content of the clipboard changes.

For Mac you would also have to use a macro program like  Keyboard Maestro or iKey. And for Linux some obscure command line tool that requires an software engineering degree to understand.