# Why is bidirectional copy/paste erring?

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to allow for bidirectional copy/pasting between my host MacOS Lion machine and my virtual Ubuntu Unity machine within Virtual box.

Hence, I specified Settings => Advanced => Shared Clipboard to be "Bidirectional." However, I cannot copy/paste from or to my Mac OS or Ubuntu.

Why? Is there something else I must do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the Virtual Box Guest Addtion on the Ubuntu guest VM?

Please refer to this: [How do I enable the shared clipboard in VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/42134/virtualbox-shared-clipboard)