# Auto launching a PuTTY SSH connection to a VirtualBox Arch Linux guest once it loads

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, virtualbox, putty

I have a Virtual Machine with Arch Linux under a Windows 8.1 host. I currently open the vm, wait until it boots (or until saved state is restored), and then connect through SSH so I can have clipboard, etc. plus spawn several terminals (I just use the console, no Desktop).

How can I automate this?

Comment: You know you can [share the clipboard](http://superuser.com/q/42134/151431) between host and guest right? Why connect through ssh if the VM is running on the same machine?

Comment: You can't without Xorg

Comment: Really? That seems strange, you can have a working clipboard without X with [`gpm`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_gpm.htm). I haven't tried it but that should let you share the clipboard between host and guest.