# VirtualBox Guest Additions broke my VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, clipboard

Guest Additions stopped working for me after a VM restart.

I saw [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/42134/virtualbox-shared-clipboard) and figured it would solve my problem. But the instructions there, [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html), and [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-guest-addons.html) all do not work for me.

I've mounted `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` on my VM, installed `VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe`, and rebooted so I can utilize the shared clipboard.

I checked that `Devices->Shared Clipboard->Bidirectional` is set correctly.

**Why is it still not working?**

On top of everything else, it seems that installing guest additions disabled my ability to rescale the VM (the Host+G option is grayed out in the View menu)

Comment: First of all, the documentation is not out of date, your copy of VirtualBox is out of date.  The current version of VirtualBox is 5.0.14.  Second, the "Devices" menu is only available from the console of a running VM, you don't show a screenshot of that.

Comment: Great point. I've mounted the .iso in the VM, run the installer, rebooted the VM, and still can't share my clipboard. On top of that, now I can't auto-scale my display with right-ctrl+G

Comment: Are the guest additions recognized (From the console, Machine -> Session Information, Runtime Information tab) and the same version as the host?

Comment: Runtime attributes->Clipboard Mode = Bidirectional

Comment: on my copy that menu option is available even if Guest Additions are not properly installed.  Please see my previous comment to check if the host recognizes the guest additions.  (Also note that for me "Auto-resize Guest Display" is disabled when additions are not installed)

Comment: I'd post a screenshot in a comment if I could, but my last comment was after checking the Runtime information you mention. I can also see `Guest Additions = 4.3.32`. Maybe it's a version issue?

Comment: It may be, although as long as Host and Guest are using the same version I would think you'd be ok.