# Virtualbox clipboard not working

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, clipboard

I have problem to make the clipboard works on my VM the informations is following

- VirtualBox Version: `5.0.20 r106931`.
- Host: `Ubuntu 16.04` *VirtualBox Extension Pack installed.*
- Guest: `Windows 10` *Guest Additions installed.*

i tried shutdown, reboot the VM many times and kill `VBoxTray` process but no help.

This is not a duplicate question i googled regrading the issue but no solution is found.

The screen resolution, shared folders and USBs are working as excepted.

How i can make it works ?

**Update**
The clipboard is seated to `Bidirectional`.
also it tried Host to guest + guest to host.

Comment: Have you actually *enabled* the shared clipboard?  The important part is to go to the Devices menu at the top of the VM, then Shared Clipboard and select one of the options. http://superuser.com/questions/42134/how-to-enable-shared-clipboard-in-virtualbox/42140#42140

Comment: @Mokubai Of course i did sorry i don't mention it

Comment: Fair enough, it would be worth editing it in to your question then.  The only reason I asked is because I spent at least 15 minutes wondering why it wouldn't work a few weeks back and it seems an easy thing to miss.

Comment: Same issue. Seems 5.20 broke the clipboard. I am on a linux host as well.

Comment: @VansS a workaround, Go to VM Options + Display + Remote Display tap + put any port number ( _use random unique port for each VM_ ) . Connect to your VM using [Remmina](http://www.remmina.org/wp/) or any RDP client you like.

Answer (score 1):

For me, OS X host virtual box 5.20, ubuntu 16.04 guest, bidirectional clipboard works with Ubuntu's Virtualbox guest package which is v5.18, but not with the Oracle extension (5.20)

Comment: `Normal` start or `Headless` start ?

Comment: My Windows guest on Os x also has bidirectional clipboard... so I guess something is not correct on your host virtual box.

Answer (score -1):

I've always had the issue with virtualbox clipboard (bi-directional). My host is debian and guest is windows 7, and I just updated to virtualbox-5.1. I had the VBoxService process running instead of the VBoxTray even tho startup program VBoxTray was selected in

> "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative
> Tools\System Configuration"

Apparently this happened due to the registry value not being set, to which it was pointing to.

> location:
>
> > HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
>
> value:
>
> > C:\Windows\System32\VBoxTray.exe

So I went ahead and created the string key in the same location, pointing to the same path, which autostarted the program on start up.

Bad news tho. clipboard does not work on headless, or detachable. One of the solutions is to connect remotely to the vm, which is ridiculous.